# Hiera can't find puppet environment

Tags: puppet, hiera, hierarchy

I'm testing out hiera and hitting a snag on the hierarchy configuration. What I have is extremely simple, the part that isn't working is specification of hiera datadir files based on environment. Here's the config file (*/etc/hiera.yaml*) I'm trying

```
---
:backends:
  - yaml
:logger: console
:hierarchy:
  - "%{::environment}"

:yaml:
   :datadir: /var/lib/hiera
```

Now, I have a file */var/lib/hiera/development.yaml*

```
blah: meh
```

When I run hiera it's not finding the file or the value

```
$ hiera -d blah
DEBUG: Fri Oct 25 15:50:52 -0600 2013: Hiera YAML backend starting
DEBUG: Fri Oct 25 15:50:52 -0600 2013: Looking up blah in YAML backend
nil
```

I've verified this agent is configured for development

```
$ sudo puppet agent --configprint environment
development
```

Now let me prove hiera is capable of finding *something*; a change to the *hiera.yaml* file:

```
:hierarchy:
  - development
```

And now hiera finds the file and the value

```
$ hiera -d blah
DEBUG: Fri Oct 25 15:53:25 -0600 2013: Hiera YAML backend starting
DEBUG: Fri Oct 25 15:53:25 -0600 2013: Looking up blah in YAML backend
DEBUG: Fri Oct 25 15:53:25 -0600 2013: Looking for data source development
DEBUG: Fri Oct 25 15:53:25 -0600 2013: Found blah in development
meh
```

So why isn't it working with the dynamic environment configuration? I got that straight from [the documentation](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/hiera/1/hierarchy.html). Note, I have tried running the `hiera` command via sudo with no change in the result.

Comment: Running the hiera command doesn't get the variables like $environment. It only gets them when it is called from puppet. So calling hiera -d blah isn't going give you much useful if your hiera configuration is purely based on variables supplied by puppet.

Comment: Thanks. How are you supposed to test then?

Comment: @quickshiftin Test Hiera in the development environment on a puppet master - the Hiera data and evaluations are on the master and not the agent, so that's the only way to test how a realistic deployment will function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to [feed hiera facts](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/hiera/1/command_line.html#fact-sources). Try `hiera -d blah environment=development`.

Comment: Looks like I had to flip the order `hiera -d blah environment=development` per `Usage: hiera [options] key [default value] [variable='text'...]`, but that's what I was looking for!